# GetList in netsuite connector in mule 4

Tags: mule, netsuite, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, cloudhub

Any one tried GetList using Netsuite connector in Mule 4 ? I couldn't use this operation because it is failing with below error :

```
"Cannot instantiate class 'org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.BaseRef'

 4| [{
  |  ...
12| }]

Trace:
  at main (line: 4, column: 2), while writing Java at 
 4| [{
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@ssdg,
BaseRef is an abstract class, Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

use  RecordRef or CustomRecordRef depending on the type of Object.
Here is the dataweave 2.0 example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
[
 {
      "type":"CUSTOMER",
      "internalId": xxxxxx,
 }as Object {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
 {
      "type":"CUSTOMER",
      "internalId": xxxx,
 }as Object {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
 {
      "type":"CUSTOMER",
      "internalId": xxxxx,
 }as Object {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
 
]
```